# timeout и смена ксс после отправки сообщения

Tags: jquery

В общем после отправки формы, хочу чтобы выскакивало модальное окно с текстом и через 5 секунд редирект на другую страницу, как это реализовать?
Есть созданное модальное окно, его вызов хочу сделать посредством смены css или как лучше? а таймаут не смог поставить, подскажите пожалуйста

```
       $.ajax({
            url:'register.php'
            , type:'POST'
            , data: JSON.stringify(formData)
            , success: function(res) {
                var jsonResult = JSON.parse(res);
                if(jsonResult.hasOwnProperty("error")){
                    $('div.result').text('Такой пользователь уже существует');
                }
                if(jsonResult.hasOwnProperty("message")){
                    $('cover').css('display:block');
                    window.location.href = "url";
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кому надо

```
            $.ajax({
                url:'register.php'
                , type:'POST'
                , data: JSON.stringify(formData)
                , success: function(res) {
                    var jsonResult = JSON.parse(res);
                    if(jsonResult.hasOwnProperty("error")){
                        $('div.result').text('Такой пользователь уже существует');
                    }
                    if(jsonResult.hasOwnProperty("message")){
                        ($(".cover").css("display", "block"));
                        ($(".modal").css("display", "block"));
                        ($(".content").css("display", "block"));
                        setTimeout('document.location.href="url";', 4000);

                    }
                }
            });
```